# How to change style of content a XSL file using C#/JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, xslt, ektron

if the value of `spnCity` is "ABC" then set `id1` to class (`tableHeading`) otherwise set `id1` to class (`tableHeading2`)

How can I access the `spnCity` span from code-behind in my Web Handler or if that is not possible, how do I access it using JQuery.

My preference is to really use C# code-behind because I have a function which does some complex operation.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
//DateTime test = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8);
string time = now.ToString("T");

static public bool IsTimeOfDayBetween(DateTime time, TimeSpan startTime, TimeSpan endTime)
{
    if (endTime == startTime)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (endTime < startTime)
    {
        return time.TimeOfDay <= endTime ||
            time.TimeOfDay >= startTime;
    }
    else
    {
        return time.TimeOfDay >= startTime &&
            time.TimeOfDay <= endTime;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked `if that is not possible, how do I access it using JQuery.`, i am writing answer to access that using `jquery`. Following is `jQuery` code to access that span value.

`$("#id1 h4 span").text().trim()`

Comment: Thank you. I am looking to get the time of day between in JQuery.